# How do I apply formatting to an HTML table in an email?

Tags: html, css, html-table, inline-styles

I generate HTML code using a SQL query. The HTML gets inserted into the body of an email, which gets sent from the database.

As part of that email, i want to have a table in the body of the email. I've figured out how to do that with some basic HTML code, but I'm struggling with formatting the table.

Here's my current code / HTML Email body text:

```
<font face="Calibri">Order Summary at 12:53<P>
            <table>
                    <thead>
                            <tr>
                            <th align="left">&nbsp Order Code</th>
                            <th align="left">Client Name &nbsp</th>
                            <th align="right">Total Orders &nbsp</th>
                            <th align="right">Orders Shipped &nbsp</th>
                            <th align="right">Exceptions: &nbsp</th>
                            <th align="center">A</th>
                            <th align="center">B</th>
                            <th align="center">C</th>
                            <th align="center">D</th>
                            <th align="center">E</th>
                            <th align="center">F</th>
                            <th align="center">G</th>
                </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                            <tr>
                            <td align="left">&nbsp A133D&nbsp</td>
                            <td align="left">&nbspTesco &nbsp</td>
                            <td align="right"> 3 &nbsp</td>
                            <td align="right"> 0 &nbsp</td>
                            <td align="right"> &nbsp </td>
                            <td align="center">&nbsp 0 &nbsp</td>
                            <td align="center">&nbsp 0 &nbsp</td>
                            <td align="center">&nbsp 0 &nbsp</td>
                            <td align="center">&nbsp 0 &nbsp</td>
                            <td align="center">&nbsp 0 &nbsp</td>
                            <td align="center">&nbsp 0 &nbsp</td>
                            <td align="center">&nbsp 0 &nbsp</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                            <td align="left">&nbsp A134D&nbsp</td>
                            <td align="left">&nbspAsda &nbsp</td>
                            <td align="right"> 2 &nbsp</td>
                            <td align="right"> 0 &nbsp</td>
                            <td align="right"> &nbsp </td>
                            <td align="center">&nbsp 0 &nbsp</td>
                            <td align="center">&nbsp 0 &nbsp</td>
                            <td align="center">&nbsp 0 &nbsp</td>
                            <td align="center">&nbsp 0 &nbsp</td>
                            <td align="center">&nbsp 0 &nbsp</td>
                            <td align="center">&nbsp 0 &nbsp</td>
                            <td align="center">&nbsp 0 &nbsp</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                            <td align="left">&nbsp A135D&nbsp</td>
                            <td align="left">&nbspMorrisons &nbsp</td>
                            <td align="right"> 1 &nbsp</td>
                            <td align="right"> 0 &nbsp</td>
                            <td align="right"> &nbsp </td>
                            <td align="center">&nbsp 0 &nbsp</td>
                            <td align="center">&nbsp 0 &nbsp</td>
                            <td align="center">&nbsp 0 &nbsp</td>
                            <td align="center">&nbsp 0 &nbsp</td>
                            <td align="center">&nbsp 0 &nbsp</td>
                            <td align="center">&nbsp 0 &nbsp</td>
                            <td align="center">&nbsp 0 &nbsp</td>
                            </tr>
                    </tbody>
           </table>
```

Very basic, but does the job well.

What I want to do is add a little visual styling to the table. Currently it appears just as black characters on a white background.

I want to put borders around all the cells of the table, so that it appears like a grid.

I also want to colour the header row to make it look nice.

Ideally I would be able to have the headings for the first four columns one colour, and the remaining 8 columns (Exceptions) another colour, but if that's very complicated to do then all headings the same colour would be perfectly fine.

Comment: This all sounds like basic CSS. Have you done any research into styling borders or background colors? Tried to implement this yourself? There are a number of tutorials available on the internet where you can teach yourself this kind of thing. Then you don't have to depend on volunteers spending their time doing your work for you...

Comment: *Actually* the purpose of this site is to create a library of high-quality questions and answers. Helping people is a byproduct of that effort. You may want to read [this answer to the question "What is the purpose of Stack Overflow?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/292176/215552).

Comment: The accepted answer uses CSS in a `style` attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In HTML for emails, you have to use HTML attributes/inline styles.

For example, on the table opening tag:

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid #55ff99;">
```

On individually coloured cells:

```html
                            <th align="left" style="color:#ffffff;background-color:#008033">&nbsp Order Code</th>
                            <th align="left" style="color:#ffffff;background-color:#008033">Client Name &nbsp</th>
                            <th align="right" style="color:#ffffff;background-color:#008033">Total Orders &nbsp</th>
                            <th align="right" style="color:#ffffff;background-color:#008033">Orders Shipped &nbsp</th>
```

Depending on how you're writing your SQL (e.g. stored procedure), you could have logic that counts the columns and sets a different style if the count is <5, or just hard-code the HTML for the first 4 headings.

Comment: A conveniant way to do it is using [Emogrifier](https://github.com/MyIntervals/emogrifier) or an alternative. It merge a *css* and an *html* string , by adding inline styling.

Comment: Happy to help :)